# When Spark finds an action does runs every line of code until the action or only the transformations that are relevant to the action?

Tags: apache-spark

Let

```
x: RDD[Int] = {1,2,3,4}

y: RDD[Int] = {4,5,6,7}
```

line 1:

```
x = x.map(x => x+1)
```

line 2:

```
y = y.map(y => y+1)
```

line 3:

```
x.collect().foreach(println)
```

will spark compute all the lines or only lines 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it will only execute lines 1 and 3. The reason why it is not executing line 2, is because you are not calling any action on RDD `y`, you are only building up the DAG on `y`.